# Executing a http request based the result of a previous request in angular 2

Tags: http, angular, request, observable

I would like to handle asynchronous stream when using Observable in Angular 2. 
In detail, before every user's request, I need to get service ticket, if that ticket is valid, user can get proper response. Therefore, I have to do http request first before actual request, as below, I call the method called getServiceTicket(), however, because of asynchronous stream, before I get the valid service ticket, the following http request (getDetail) is performed without valid service ticket. So I tried to use flag like isServiceTicket, but I realize it does not guarantee the sequential running of these two methods. I tried to do some research, but I could not find satisfactory answer. If someone has good solution for this, could you give some advice?

```js
getServiceTicket() {
    this.userAuthServie.getServiceTicket().subscribe(
        (data: string) => {this.serviceTicket = data; this.isServiceTicket = true;}
    );
}

getDetail(id: string) { 
    this.getServiceTicket();
    return this.http.get('https://localhost/detail/' + id + '?ticket=' + this.serviceTicket)
    .map( (responseData) => {
        return <User>responseData.json();
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe your are looking for this: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Answer (score 0):

You can change yor code like below:

```
user:User;

      getDetail(id: string) {

        this.userAuthServie.getServiceTicket()
          .subscribe((data: string) => {
            this.serviceTicket = data;
            this.isServiceTicket = true;
            this.http.get('https://localhost/detail/' + id + '?ticket=' + this.serviceTicket)
              .map( (responseData) => {
                this.user= <User>responseData.json();
              });
          });

      }
```

Comment: If I do this way, I get the "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined".

Comment: Provide the code getServiceTicket in UserAuthService

Comment: Thank you so much. Following is getServiceTicket from UserAuthService.
   getServiceTicket() {
    let cuser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cUser'));
    let creds = "servicename=http://xxx.xxx.xxx";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    if(cuser.token) {
      return this.http.post('https://localhost/serviceTicket/' + cuser.token + '?serviceName=http://xxx.xxx.xxx', creds, { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
    }
  }

Comment: you should return an observable too in case where there's no cuser.token

Answer (score 0):

You can place the second function that you want to run in the success part of the subscribe method of the first function.

```js
getServiceTicket() {
    this.userAuthServie.getServiceTicket().subscribe(
        (data: string) => {
            this.serviceTicket = data; this.isServiceTicket = true;
            this.getDetail(id);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have one more question, the reason why I have implemented that way is that I wanted to implement the method that gets the service ticket separately which means whenever I need service ticket, I  wanted to call that method before actual http request and get the service ticket and pass that service ticket to the real http request method. If I implement this way, I have to repeat following code. "this.userAuthServie.getServiceTicket().subscribe(" so...

Comment: You could either have two separate methods to do so or simply make an if statement within the same method to perform or not perform the part you're referring to based on a boolean you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the service ticket to be loaded before any "detail requests" are performed, you should wait on the response of service ticket to resolve. There are multiple ways, one way might be to add the details to a queue, or have getDetails wait until the service ticket is loaded.

```
getServiceTicket() {
    // you need to return the observable from service ticket
    return this.userAuthServie
       .getServiceTicket()
       // use map here to only intercept the value.
       // remember that you need to subscribe somewhere else
       // if called from elsewhere than getDetail
       .map((data: string) => {
           this.serviceTicket = data;
           this.isServiceTicket = true;
           return data;
       });
}

getDetail(id: string) {
    return this.getServiceTicket()
        // we switch the observable from ticket to the one from detail using switchMap
        .switchMap((data: string) => {
            let url = 'https://localhost/detail/' + id + '?ticket=' + this.serviceTicket;
            return this.http
                .get(url)
                .map((responseData) => {
                    return <User>responseData.json();
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I get this "Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'. If you have some clue, could you please give some explanation about this?

Comment: What was the issue with switchMap?